# SpringMVC forwards to wrong view name

Tags: spring-mvc

I have created a method which returns a ModelAndView in order to display a list with a jsp "resourcelist".  It executes the method showResourceList() but after the return, I get a 404 error on /WEB-INF/views/resources.jsp.
"The resource requested is not found".

But in my views, there is no jsp named resources.jsp.  I don't understand why it tries to find this view which doesn't exist.  As you can see in my controller's code, I'm trying to forward to resourcelist.jsp and not to resources.jsp.

I've many other controllers returning a ModelAndView which work just fine.

Can anybody help me ?

Here’s the  code :

```
package learningresourcefinder.controller;

import java.util.List;

import learningresourcefinder.model.Resource;
import learningresourcefinder.repository.ResourceRepository;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class RessourceListController extends BaseController<Resource>{
    @Autowired ResourceRepository resourcerepository; 

    @RequestMapping("/resources")
    public ModelAndView showResourceList () {
        List<Resource> list=resourcerepository.findAllRessourceOrderByTitle();
        return new ModelAndView("resourcelist", "resourceList", list);
    }
}
```

Many thanks!
Sébastien.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `@RequestMapping("/resources")` after the `@Controller` annotation  and then have a `String` of the correct mapping/view as the return value in the `showResourceList()` method. So, for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/resources")
public class RessourceListController extends BaseController<Resource>{
    ...

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showResourcesList(ModelMap model) {
        // retrieve the list instance
        model.addAttribute("resourcesList", list);

        return "/resources/resourceslist";
    }
    ...
}
```

Also, how is your `viewResolver` bean configured in your Spring configuration?

Comment: Hi, i've compared with another classes and i've seen i've done a wrong import. I had imported "springframework.web.servlet.Modelandview" instead importing "springframework.web.portlet.Modelandview".

Answer (score 0):

i've compared with another classes and i've seen i've done a wrong import. I had imported "springframework.web.**servlet**.Modelandview" instead importing "springframework.web.**portlet**.Modelandview".
Sorry...